What are next steps after fitting glmmTMB model?
I recently underwent the process of fitting a GLMM model using the glmmTMB package in R. I'm now a little stumped on where to go from here for using it to interpret the data and create visuals for publication. I created this model to help predict acoustic detections in 7 different sound classes according to the environmental data I collected. Now, with a model that excludes many of the variables, I'm unsure whether my next step should be Tukey tests to get directional data on statistically significant predictor variables, or something else, and I'm not finding particularly thorough guides for how to plot this model or make visuals that represent it.
I have used ggplot2 in the past to create visuals, but those were with raw data and not with a model. Similarly, up to this point, most of my data analysis experience has been with raw data and I don't know how to incorporate this model into the analysis workflow.
I'm including my model-fitting code in case it's helpful or there are any glaring mistakes in my process.
#install necessary packages
install.packages("glmmTMB")
install.packages("TMB", type = "source")
library(TMB)
library(glmmTMB)
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
install.packages("DHARMa")
library(DHARMa)
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
install.packages("corrplot")
library(corrplot)
install.packages("car")
library(car)
install.packages("ggeffects")
library(ggeffects)

#import data
Merged_Data <- read.csv("C:/Users/.../Merged_Data.csv")

#remove unused columns
Merged_Data <- Merged_Data[, !(colnames(Merged_Data) %in% c("X", "Begin.Path", "Coordinates"))]
Merged_Data <- Merged_Data[, !(colnames(Merged_Data) == "Dist.To.Tree.Average")]

#Removing na values. Want to remove na but not entire variables
#For structural (height, canopy, diameter, density), replace na with 0 because indicates unforested area
Merged_Data$Height.Average[is.na(Merged_Data$Height.Average)] <- 0
Merged_Data$Canopy.Average[is.na(Merged_Data$Canopy.Average)] <- 0
Merged_Data$Average.Density[is.na(Merged_Data$Average.Density)] <- 0
Merged_Data$Diameter.Average[is.na(Merged_Data$Diameter.Average)] <- 0

#For temp/relative humidity (RH) replace with mean to account for missing data due to technical difficulties
Merged_Data$Average.Humidity[is.na(Merged_Data$Average.Humidity)] <-mean(Merged_Data$Average.Humidity, na.rm=TRUE)
Merged_Data$Average.Temperature[is.na(Merged_Data$Average.Temperature)] <-mean(Merged_Data$Average.Temperature, na.rm=TRUE)

#Group detections (and everything??) by Sound Class
##Look into this to make sure it's not screwing anything up
Merged_Data %>%
  group_by(Sound.Class)

#Factor variables as factors
Merged_Data$Site <- as.factor(Merged_Data$Site)
Merged_Data$Sound.Class <- as.factor(Merged_Data$Sound.Class) #Not necessary now that Grouped by sound class?
Merged_Data$Habitat <- as.factor(Merged_Data$Habitat)
Merged_Data$Hour <-as.factor(Merged_Data$Hour)

#Numeric variables as numbers
Merged_Data$Height.Average <- as.numeric(Merged_Data$Height.Average)
Merged_Data$Average.Temperature <- as.numeric(Merged_Data$Average.Temperature)

#Scale numeric variables using mutate to equally weight each variable in model
Merged_Data <- Merged_Data %>%
  mutate(
    Avg.Height.Sc = as.numeric(scale(Height.Average)),
    Avg.Diameter.Sc = as.numeric(scale(Diameter.Average)),
    Avg.Canopy.Sc = as.numeric(scale(Canopy.Average)), 
    Avg.Density.Sc = as.numeric(scale(Average.Density)), 
    Avg.RH.Sc = as.numeric(scale(Average.Humidity)),
    Avg.Temp.Sc = as.numeric(scale(Average.Temperature))
  )

#combine related variables into single predictor (PCA), Sound.Class as fixed effect
##make sure can do this with glmmtmb
pca <- prcomp(Merged_Data[, c("Avg.Height.Sc", "Avg.Diameter.Sc", "Avg.Canopy.Sc")], scale. = TRUE)
Merged_Data$PC1 <- pca$x[, 1]

#combine temp and RH
pca2 <- prcomp(Merged_Data[, c("Avg.Temp.Sc", "Avg.RH.Sc")], scale. = TRUE)
Merged_Data$PC2 <- pca$x[, 1]
#ensure merged data is data frame after mutations
class(Merged_Data)

#Go through fit process
# Basic model: Only random intercept for 'Site'
TMB_simple <- glmmTMB(Detection ~ 1 + (1 | Site), 
                      data = Merged_Data, 
                      family = nbinom2)
summary(TMB_simple)

TMB_habitat <- glmmTMB(Detection ~ Habitat + (1 | Site), 
                       data = Merged_Data, 
                       family = nbinom2)
summary(TMB_habitat)

TMB_sound <- glmmTMB(Detection ~ Habitat + Sound.Class + (1 | Site), 
                     data = Merged_Data, 
                     family = nbinom2)

summary(TMB_sound)

#height didn't help so trying PCA
TMB_PCA  <- glmmTMB(Detection ~ Habitat + Sound.Class + PC1
                       + (1 | Site), 
                       data = Merged_Data, 
                       family = nbinom2)

summary(TMB_PCA)

#density doesn't help, so removing it
TMB_dens  <- glmmTMB(Detection ~ Habitat + Sound.Class + Avg.Density.Sc
                    + (1 | Site), 
                    data = Merged_Data, 
                    family = nbinom2)

summary(TMB_dens)

#Temp improves AIC, BIC, and doesn't really impact overdispersion. Is significant
TMB_temp  <- glmmTMB(Detection ~ Habitat + Sound.Class + PC1 + Avg.Temp.Sc
                     + (1 | Site), 
                     data = Merged_Data, 
                     family = nbinom2)

summary(TMB_temp)

#try RH without temp-isn't as good. 
TMB_RH  <- glmmTMB(Detection ~ Habitat + Sound.Class + PC1 + Avg.RH.Sc
                     + (1 | Site), 
                     data = Merged_Data, 
                     family = nbinom2)

summary(TMB_RH)

#together?
TMB_TR  <- glmmTMB(
  Detection ~ Habitat + Sound.Class + PC1 + Avg.RH.Sc + Avg.Temp.Sc
                   + (1 | Site), 
                   data = Merged_Data, 
                   family = nbinom2)

summary(TMB_TR)

#without PCA improves fit but leave until random effects are there
TMB_noPCA  <- glmmTMB(
  Detection ~ Habitat + Sound.Class + Avg.RH.Sc + Avg.Temp.Sc
  + (1 | Site), 
  data = Merged_Data, 
  family = nbinom2)

summary(TMB_noPCA)

#time made a big difference
TMB_hour  <- glmmTMB(
  Detection ~ Habitat + Sound.Class + PC1 + Avg.RH.Sc + Avg.Temp.Sc
  + (1 | Site) + (1 | Hour), 
  data = Merged_Data, 
  family = nbinom2)

summary(TMB_hour)

#add zero inflation with PCA
#Have to remove either temp or RH and RH is seemingly slightly better predictor
#similar AIC value to tmb_zi but theoretically includes less multicollinearity and more complete data
TMB_zi1  <- glmmTMB(
  Detection ~ Habitat + Sound.Class + PC1 + Avg.RH.Sc
  + (1 | Site) + (1 | Hour), 
  ziformula = ~ Habitat + Sound.Class, 
  data = Merged_Data, 
  family = nbinom2)

summary(TMB_zi1)
AIC(TMB_zi1)
BIC(TMB_zi1)

#add zero inflation
#nbinom1 doesn't work with model so stick with nbinom2
TMB_zi  <- glmmTMB(
  Detection ~ Habitat + Sound.Class + Avg.RH.Sc + Avg.Temp.Sc
  + (1 | Site) + (1 | Hour), 
  ziformula = ~ Habitat + Sound.Class, 
  data = Merged_Data, 
  family = nbinom2())

summary(TMB_zi)
AIC(TMB_zi)
BIC(TMB_zi)

#check for quadratic or cubic values in the model
TMB_quad  <- glmmTMB(
  Detection ~ Habitat + Sound.Class + Avg.RH.Sc + poly(Avg.Temp.Sc, 2)
  + (1 | Site) + (1 | Hour), 
  ziformula = ~ Habitat + Sound.Class, 
  data = Merged_Data, 
  family = nbinom2)

summary(TMB_quad)
AIC(TMB_quad)

#check for interaction
TMB_int  <- glmmTMB(
  Detection ~ Sound.Class + Habitat * poly(Avg.RH.Sc, 3)
  + (1 | Hour), 
  ziformula = ~ Habitat + Sound.Class, 
  data = Merged_Data, 
  family = nbinom2)

AIC(TMB_int)
summary(TMB_int)
sim_res2 <- simulateResiduals(TMB_int)
plot(sim_res2)

#test quadratic or cubic terms
#test removing site and it slightly improves AIC and BIC and removes NaN values
#remove PC1 b/c not significant
#these changes improve residual plot
TMB  <- glmmTMB(
  Detection ~ Habitat + Sound.Class + poly(Avg.RH.Sc, 3)
   + (1 | Hour), 
  ziformula = ~ Habitat + Sound.Class, 
  data = Merged_Data, 
  family = nbinom2)

summary(TMB)
#This is the winner model with the best AIC/BIC/dispersion, and significant values of included variables

#testing for over dispersion
dispersion <- sum(residuals(TMB, type = "pearson")^2) / df.residual(TMB)
dispersion
sim_res <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = TMB)
testDispersion(sim_res)
#residuals look pretty good
#check ANOVA values
if (requireNamespace("car") && getRversion()) {
  Anova(TMB)
}


ANOVA results:
Response: Detection
Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
Habitat              30.832  2  2.018e-07
Sound.Class        1694.677  6  < 2.2e-16
poly(Avg.RH.Sc, 3)  117.656  3  < 2.2e-16
Signif. codes: the three variables are significant at the 1% level significance
Thanks so much in advance for any help/advice. I appreciate it.
Happy Holidays!!

Have you looked at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/model_evaluation.pdf ? Also, several newer packages marginaleffects, sjPlot, performance, insight, ggeffects can be used with glmmTMB models ...  If you know what to do with a simpler model (e.g. a 1-way ANOVA), you should be able to follow analogous steps with this model ...

Thanks Ben. I have looked at the website referenced and it's helpful to an extent but it offers little in the way of explanatory information and follows more of a "copy and you'll get these results" format. This is my first time using a model for statistical analysis, so although I have some stats experience, I'm looking for some more guidance on how to translate this model into meaningful terms, and on a workflow to identify key characteristics for a model without trying every suggestion in the vignette. For example, should I look into Tukey results or is using the effects package sufficient?
